# Curl works to POST data to FastAPI but React throws 422

Tags: python, reactjs, curl, fastapi

I am writing a simple React application that takes form data and submits it to a Python API. The API is written in FastAPI and looks like this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
import json

app = FastAPI()


class TextInfer(BaseModel):
    text: str


@app.get("/")
def hello():
    return "hello"


@app.post("/predict")
def predict(req: TextInfer):
    return req
```

cURL works to send a simple JSON object to the `predict` endpoint:

```
> curl  -d '{"text": "sample text"}' -H  "Accept: application/json"  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://0.0.0.0/predict
> {"text":"sample text"}%
```

But the React `fetch` call always results in a 422:

```
fetch('http://0.0.0.0/predict', {
      method: 'POST', 
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({'text': this.state.text})
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            predictions: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error: error
          });
        }
      )
```

`this.state.text` is a simple string; I've checked the browser console to verify that

```
{'text': this.state.text}
```

is a valid JSON object. It appears to be, e.g. `{"text": "blah"}`.

The response always reads as:

```
[HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity 13ms]
Object { msg: "value is not a valid dict", type: "type_error.dict", loc: […] }
loc [ "body" ]
```

I am guessing this has something to do with how I implemented the Pydantic model, or how I am calling `fetch` from React, or both. Looking at similar questions has not helped resolve the issue. I also tried hard coding the `body` of the `fetch` call (in case my use of JSON.stringify was incorrect), but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

in

```
@app.post("/predict")
def predict(req: TextInfer):
    return req
```

you send back string, because you change json to string on line  `body: JSON.stringify({'text': this.state.text})`

can you check what value is there?
if it is truly string then you can just parse that string.

In python you can use just import json library like `import json` and then change last line from `return req` to `return json.loads(req)`